# Is it possible to do DbSaveChange piecemeal (EF Core 6)

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am using EF Core 6, is it possible to split the operation to be done in `SaveChanges` method after range methods to split very big data into pieces

```
int x = 250;

for (int i = 0; i < datas.Count;)
{
    var data = datas.Skip(i).Take(x).ToList();
    db.AddRange(data);
    db.SaveChanges();

    i = i + x;
}
```

If EF Core is doing a similar fragmentation, how should it be set?

Comment: Maybe you need one of the existent BulkCopy EF Core extensions?

Comment: i don't want to use extra library should be possible in efcore

Comment: Massive insert is a weak part of EF Core, also because it retrieves generated keys by database and you may encounter serious delays and deadlocks. Anyway, there is `options => options.MaxBatchSize(...)`

Comment: @ZaferKırık You already use `Skip` and `Take` to split the data you have to add and save, what exactly is the question/problem you have?

Comment: I think you want .Skip(i * x).Take(x)

Comment: *If EF Core is doing a similar fragmentation, how should it be set?* The more I look at it the less I understand the question. I *think* you should use a new context instance in each loop iteration.

Comment: I'm already splitting the data, splitting the operation is my purpose

Comment: Dividing 10000 data by 1000 and running savechange 10 times